# "SSL connection error: protocol version mismatch QMYSQL: Unable to connect"

Tags: mysql, windows, qt, openssl, mariadb

my Qt application, when running on Windows, returns the title error when connecting to a remote MySql database on my server. This does not happen when compiled for Linux. The application uses ssl certificates to login to the database. Seems that the problem started few weeks ago when on my archlinux server openssl updated from 1.1.1.q to 3.0.7. I tried to downgrade the installation to a date prior to new openssl release and my application works again in Windows too. But I would prefer keep the server update.

Can anyone give me some clue about the problem? If needed I can give more info about server settings.

Very thanks

Comment: It could be because you are using Qt version (for windows) which is compiled with older version. If your Windows Qt binary is compiled statically, then you need to recompile with newer open ssl or if its linked dynamically try replacing the older open ssl with newer ones and see if it works

Comment: What is the tls protocol version after downgrade (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ssl_version'`) ?